# Laravel 8 - Calling multiple factory states at once

Tags: laravel, testing, factory

Pre Laravel 8 there seems to be an option to line up different states at once

`$users = factory(App\User::class, 5)->states('premium', 'delinquent')->make();`
(edit: I now realise that this was to apply 2 different states into the same factory record)

whereas I can't seem to find the equivalent of this in Laravel 8, does anybody know how?

Essentially I am trying to call one chain to create multiple records with different states for example:

`User::factory()->verified()->unverified()->banned()->create()`

Result: 3 different users one verified one unverified one banned

It can be achieved with below code, it just seems a little verbose

```
User::factory()->verified()->create();       
User::factory()->unverified()->create();       
User::factory()->banned()->create();
```

Comment: How can one be both verified *and* unverified?

Comment: Right now I would need to to
      `User::factory()->verified()->create();
      User::factory()->unverified()->create();
      User::factory()->banned()->create();`

Which does work to be honest, just didn't necessarily feel like the laravel way so thought it would be good to ask.

PS: The User is not verified and unverified at the same time. They are 3 different users as per the Result:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1. Get rid of states and just use sequences

```php
User::factory()
->count(3)
->state(new Sequence(
    ['status' => 'verified'],
    ['status' => 'unverified'],
    ['status' => 'banned'],
))
->create()
```

## 2. Use variables as functions

Keep your current states, but dynamically access them from a predefined list.

```php
$states = ['verified', 'unverified', 'banned'];
foreach ($states as $state) {
    User::factory()->$state()->create();
}
```

## 3. Write each one out by hand.

Similar to number 2, but we don't use a loop.

```php
User::factory()->verified()->create();
User::factory()->unverified()->create();
User::factory()->banned()->create();
```

Comment: Thanks, what a great answer.

I like option 1 since I never considered this before, yet it is still quite verbose in more complex situations.
Option 2 - is probably the most elegant way in my opinion it was staring at me right in the face I don't know how I couldn't think of that :)